# Enable web socket streaming in Bot Framework Composer BOT

Tags: node.js, direct-line-botframework

I have a nodeJS bot built with the composer.

I'm attempting to enable telephony. I followed the directions that were laid out on GitHub, however, when I call I get dead air. Then the telephony channel on the bot shows an error that it could not connect to my bot. Web sockets and streaming are enabled on the app but it looks as if the code needs to be updated as well.

Where do you enable web sockets in the nodeJS code built with composer?

Answer (score 0):

> it looks as if the code needs updated as well. Where do you enable web sockets in the nodeJS code built with composer?

It is set up to use WebSockets already. I don't know if you need something special for telephony or not. Please see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/eb58d15b67405fe11a9bcdf958ff5a241feced97/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs-adaptive-runtime-integration-express/src/index.ts#L186).

> when I call I get dead air

My assumption is that it is something else.